# Finding the size of a Mongo::Collection::View

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongodb-ruby

I am trying to find the size of the result of a query in MongoDB and ruby:

```
size = collection.find({ foo: 'bar' }).size
if size > 0
  print "There are #{size} results!"
else
  print "There aren't any results."
end
```

However, when I run this, I get the following error:

```
undefined method `size' for #<Mongo::Collection::View:0x00000004141d48>
```

How do I determine the number of items returned by this query properly? I couldn't find any information in the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
collection.find({ foo: 'bar' }).count()
```

should solve your problem.  There is no size method available in mongo but there is count.